# Get history of file operations in Windows?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to get a history of file operations in Windodws, like which folders were moved where, last renamed file, what was deleted, etc.?

Comment: Try this freeware program:
http://www.trisunsoft.com/windows-explorer-tracker/

Answer (score 3):

**[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)** by SysInternals can monitor and log all file, registry and network operations.

[image: procmon.exe]

You have to be careful though. In the screenshot above, even though it says `CreateFile` all access is read-only (libraries (DLLs) being loaded).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such log by default.

---

On a Windows NT system, an administrator can enable auditing of file operations:

[image: Auditing settings for a directory]

However:

1. For this to work, "Audit object access" must be enabled in `secpol.msc`:

   [image: Secpol: Auditing]

   The moment you turn it on, you will get flooded by miscellaneous object access logs.
2. Audit logs of the entire filesystem will fill up the Security log *really fast*. I'm not going to talk about performance hits.